# Deleting all objects by substring

Tags: python, loops

Consider the following simple environment:

```
x1 = 5
x2 = 1
x3 = 100
y = 'Desk'

deletes = [x for x in dir() if x.lower().startswith('x')]
print(deletes)

for i in deletes:
    del i

print(x1)
```

I want to delete all objects in my current environment *that begin with* a certain substring, in this case such that only `y` remains. However, Python still recognizes `x1` when I `print` it below the loop, which means it's not yet been deleted. I know I could just do

```
del x1, x2, x3
```

, but I don't want to because I want to be able to delete all objects to the **n-th** degree, and would not want to do `del x1...,x100` for every single object in question. How do I fix this?

Comment: On module level you can remove it from the dict returned by `globals()`. `del i` removes the variable `i` without caring about its content.

Comment: `del i` just deletes the loop variable, not the global variable it refers to.

Comment: `del` **does not delete objects**. This is *crucial to understand**. Python is a memory managed language, and gives you no way to delete an object.